IF THEN selecting hypothetical sheet in VBA
Trying to build a macro in Excel, unfortunately our reporting system generates inconsistent sheet tab names - so referencing a specific name only works some of the time.
Example:
Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Non-var Cr sects have Cr Hr"
Sheets("Page1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$12286").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    "=None", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OR"

Occasionally the "Page1" will be "Page1_2" - is there a basic IF THEN statement that would select whichever is available without error? I looked and found similar questions but couldn't quite convert the applicability to my unique situation. I'm not outstanding with VBA, full disclosure. Not sure if I should put an IF THEN statement at the beginning of this rather long macro or use it for each individual instance in which the dynamic reference comes up.
Thanks in advance!
I've tried some very simple IF statements encompassing all the code, but maybe I should have the IF THEN statement in front of each individual occurrence of the dynamic reference.

The code of  "the reporting system" should probably be amended. Could you share it? Is this code located in the workbook containing these sheets? What is the name of the sheet where you're freezing panes? If you add 10 sheets like this you'll have a hard time dealing with them later. If .Range("$A$1:$AL$12286") references all your data and if it has no empty rows or columns, you can make it dynamic (still working after you add/remove rows of bottom data) by using .Range("A1").CurrentRegion instead. Study How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA.

When you say Occasionally the "Page1" will be "Page1_2", should we understand that it will be "Page1" OR "Page1_2"? Or it also can be "Page1" AND "Page1_2"? If like in the last assumption, what do you like it to return? "Sheet1" or the last occurrence? Something as "Sheet1_8"?

@FaneDuru - good question! It's always either "Page1" OR "Page1_2" - the reports will generate a file and every instance will be either one of the two.

@VBasic2008 thanks for the head's up - I recorded all of this using a Macro, so I'm guessing the VBA could be cleaner. I'll look into how to avoid using .select.

Then, the function can be simpler. But it MUST WORK as it is, if you use it correctly, I think.

There a few ways you could do this - here's one:
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Page1", "Page1_2"   'add other possible sheet names that you want to apply the following operation on
            ws.Range("$A$1:$AL$12286").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="=None", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OR"
            Exit For
        ' insert additional Case blocks as needed for different sheetname(s) + operation pairs            
    End Select
Next ws

Note that this assumes that the sheet names are at least in some way deterministic so that you know what to check for. If they can be wildly different each time, then you'll need to modify.
Also note that I didn't Select the sheet, and instead just referenced the sheet and range directly in the AutoFilter statement. Selecting is generally very slow and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Using the correct collection will prevent an error from occurring when the workbook contains charts i.e. For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets. You could simplify the cases with Case "Page1", "Page1_2": Exit For and continue with If Not ws Is Nothing Then: ws.Range(... when there would be no need for the sheetName variable.

Great suggestions - edited to include! Could we take it a step further and just include the ws.Range(... in the Case block? If we know the correct ws.Name exists, then we don't need to check If Not ws Is Nothing, correct? Or would you still separate it and check for safety?

IMO either way is fine. It looks better to me like this (the End Select shifted a tab to the left) because you could easily add more operations or a MsgBox that would complain if the sheet wasn't found. I am lately experimenting with adding additional (descriptive) booleans e.g. IsSheetFound = True before Exit For and continue with If IsSheetFound Then and I mostly like that kind of (over-)readability.

Yah, I was editing on phone and my spacing got all messed up. I like the compactness of doing it all in the Select Case block, so made the change above. I do also like the idea of using descriptive variables for readability too!

I appreciate all the feedback! Unfortunately, I still get an error message at ' Sheets("Page1").Select ' .. I have the code you wrote above right under my "Sub name()" and above the rest of the code I started with. Maybe that's the wrong place for it?

Try replacing the code in your example Sub after the Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet lines with the code in the answer. If you need to keep the Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Non-var Cr sects have Cr Hr" operation then you can include it in the Case block - probably want to change it to ws.Name = "Non-var Cr sects have Cr Hr" (though I'm not sure exactly what your Sub is fully doing with that line.

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
Case "Page1", "Page1_2"
ws.Range("$A$1:$AL$12286").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="=None",   Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OR"
Exit For
End Select
Next ws
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Page1").Select
@RobBennett Last line is still the issue. Code starts after last "Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet", as per your suggestion. It's possible what I'm trying to do can't be done in VBA, as well, I'm not knowledgeable enough to know. (Sorry it's all just a single paragraph)

What exactly are you trying to do with your Select statement? Do you actually need to select the sheets and make them active? Right now, your code just Selects 2 different sheets in a row, so the first line is a waste anyway because it immediately gets unselected when the 2nd line runs. From what I can tell you don't need those lines at all, but I'm only seeing the code you posted.

@RobBennett Essentially I copy/paste those two lines into a new tab, then go back to the original sheet and undo the filtering and start over. It's quite a bit of code. I'd include it all here but it's too long, I think. I appreciate you taking the time, though! I think this problem just can't be overcome in VBA.

You can still reference the cells you want to paste into and set the Value property directly instead of Selecting. The error you're getting is because you're trying to Select a sheet that doesn't exist. Try moving the relevant lines up into the Case block before Exit For, and refer to the cell you want to paste into as ws.Cells(row,col).Value= Foo. (Replace row,col, and Foo with your specific info). Hope this helps - let me know if you have any other q's.

Please, try the next function. It is able to extract the first occurrence of a sheet name with "Sheet1 - Sheet1_##" pattern. I mean, if more such sheets, most probably the most recent will be the one having the maximum suffix - this code considers this one as the last occurrence:
'it extracts first or last sheet name occurrence, based on boolFirstOccurrence boolean variable value:
Function extractSheet1(wb As Workbook, Optional boolFirstOccurrence As Boolean = True) As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
      Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not extractSheet1 Is Nothing Then
        If boolFirstOccurrence Then
            Set extractSheet1 = ws: Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    For i = 1 To 10 'MAX suffix to be checked (it can be increased...):
        On Error Resume Next
         Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1" & "_" & i)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            If boolFirstOccurrence Then
                Set extractSheet1 = ws: Exit Function
            Else
                Set ws1 = ws
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set extractSheet1 = ws1
End Function

It can be used, tested with a sub like the next one:
Sub testExtractSheet1()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = extractSheet1(ActiveWorkbook) 'call it for extracting the FIRST sheet name occurrence
  MsgBox ws.Name
  
  Set ws = extractSheet1(ActiveWorkbook, False) 'call it for extracting the LAST sheet name occurrence
  MsgBox ws.Name
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
Edit:
Please, test the next simpler version able to return (only) "Sheet1" or "Sheet1_2" sheets:
Function setSheet(wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet1_2" Then
        Set setSheet = ws: Exit For
    End If
  Next ws
End Function

It can be tested in such a testing Sub:
Sub testSetSheet()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  On Error Resume Next
   Set sh = setSheet(ActiveWorkbook)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not sh Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print sh.Name, sh.Parent.Name
  Else
    Debug.Print "No such sheets in workbook """ & ActiveWorkbook.Name & """"
  End If
End Sub

It returns the sheet name and the (active) workbook name...
Your code will become:
Sub OriginalSub()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 
 Set sh = setSheet(ActiveWorkbook)
 sh.Name = "Non-var Cr sects have Cr Hr"
 
 sh.AutoFilter
 sh.Range("$A$1:$AL$12286").AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:= _
                     "=None", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OR"
End Sub

I did not place any error handling **in case of no "Sheet1" or "Sheet1_2" sheets in the active workbook...

@Rob Bennett Didn't you find some time to test the above answer? If tested, doesn't it return what you need? Does it look too complicated, or what?

I appreciate your feedback! I keep getting an "expected end sub" error - which makes me think that maybe I have this code in the wrong place?

@Rob Bennett Did you copy the answer code exactly as it is? It MUST work. You, probably did not copy the ending End Sub of the testing Sub.  I will edit the answer and place a simpler function to return only in case of Sheet1 OR Sheet1_2.

@Rob Bennett Please, test the solution I supplied after Edit and send some feedback.

I'm not entirely sure where to place the function. Within the greater sub? I've  got nearly 1,000 lines of code, and I'm just not sure exactly how to nest this function in here.
When I try just pasting it near the top of the sub (but within the sub) it seems to cause an issue with the sub itself.

@Rob Bennett  A function is a function... It must not be included in any Sub. So, place it as a separate procedure wherever you want. The best idea would be to place it immediately after the sub which calls it. But, did you test the answer code as it is? I mean, copying the function and the testing sub (testSetSheet) in the same standard module and run this testSetSheet. Didn't it return what you need?
